# Perforce login through active directory

Tags: active-directory, perforce

Ok, so i'm reading about integrating Perforce users with Windows Server users.

I've read about triggers and all, but something is not very clear to me... So i will be glad if someone can help me.

- Will i need to create the Users/Groups inside the Perforce server still?

Because from what i understood, the triggers are just for the authentication, but there's no way to share the User's database between Perforce and those inside Active Directory.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't answer definitively, but I believe the answer is "yes", as the licensing model requires knowledge of "active users", which are created in the Perforce system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  You will not however need to create passwords for them once the AD integration is up and running.  You can add them en masse via command line with a perl script, something similar to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

use strict;
my $InFile;
my $UserID;
my $FullName;
my $Email;
my $CreatedCount = 0;
my $AlreadyExistsCount = 0;
my $FailedCount = 0;
my $Cmd;
my $Out;
my $TmpFile="add_users.user.txt";
my $NoOp = 0;

if (($#ARGV == -1) or ($ARGV[0] =~ /^(-h|-\?|\/h|\/\?)$/i))
{
   print "\nUsage:\n\n\tadd_users.pl VCS_Users_CSV.txt\n\n";
   print "The user list file must contain one-line entries looking like this sample:\n";
   print "\ta200991,Tom Tyler,p4.ttyler\@gmail.com\n\n";
   print "The Perforce environment values for P4PORT and P4USER must be\n";
   print "defined, and the user provided must be a Perforce super users.\n";
   exit 1;
} else {
   $InFile=$ARGV[0];
   die "ERROR: Input file [$InFile] is not readable.\n"
      unless (-r $InFile);
}


$Cmd = "p4 -s info";
$Out = `$Cmd 2>&1`;
if ($Out =~ /info: User name/i) {
   print "\nPerforce server info:\n$Out\n";
} else {
   die "\nERROR: Could not do a 'p4 info'.  Perforce environment is not set.\n";
}

$Cmd = "p4 -s protect -o";
$Out = `$Cmd 2>&1`;
if ($Out =~ /info: Protections:/) {
   print "\nPerforce super user status is verified.\n";
} else {
   die "\nERROR: The current Perforce user is not a super user, and must be.  Aborting.\n";
}

open (INFILE, "<$InFile") or
   die "\nERROR: Failed to open input file [$InFile]: $!\n";

while (<INFILE>) {
   next unless (/.+,.+,.+$/);
   s/\s*$//g;
   $UserID = $_;
   $UserID =~ s/,.*$//g;
   $FullName = $_;
   $FullName =~ s/^.*?,//;
   $FullName =~ s/,.*$//g;
   $Email = $_;
   $Email =~ s/^.*,//;

   unless ($Email =~ /\@/) {
      print "Error: Invalid email addresss [$Email] for user [$UserID].  Skipping.\n";
      $FailedCount++;
      next;
   }

   $Cmd = "p4 -s user -o $UserID";
   $Out = `$Cmd 2>&1`;
   if ($Out =~ /info: Access:/)
   {
      print "User [$UserID] already exists.  Skipping.\n";
      $AlreadyExistsCount++;
   } else {
      print "Creating account [$UserID] for [$FullName] ($Email).\n";
      open (USERFILE, ">$TmpFile") or die "\nERROR: Failed to open temp file [$TmpFile]: $!\n";
      print USERFILE "User:\t$UserID\n\nEmail:\t$Email\n\nFullName:\t$FullName\n\n";
      close (USERFILE);
      $Cmd = "p4 -s user -f -i < $TmpFile";
      if ($NoOp == 0) {
         $Out = `$Cmd 2>&1`;
      } else {
         print "NO-OP: Would run $Cmd\n";
         # Spoof successful user creation
         $Out = "info: User $UserID saved [NO-OP - user creation spoofed].\n";
      }

      if ($Out =~ /info: User .* saved./) {
         print $Out;
         $CreatedCount++;
      } else {
         print $Out;
         print "\nError: Failed to create user [$UserID].  Skipping.\n";
         $FailedCount++;
      }
   }
}

close (INFILE);

print "\nDone.\n\nSummary: $CreatedCount users created, $AlreadyExistsCount already existed, $FailedCount failed.\n\n";
```

You will need a text doc with the appropriate data of course, for this script it would look something like this

User ID, FirstName LastName, email@emailaddress.com

Once thats done just run a few lines from CMD:

```
   C:\Users\a200991> SET P4USER=a200991
   C:\Users\a200991> SET P4PORT=pmperforce01p:1666
   C:\Users\a200991> add_users.pl VCS_Users_CSV.txt > add_users.log 2>&1
   C:\Users\a200991> notepad add_users.log
```